# Understanding Bayes Factor in BayesFactor Package

Tags: bayesian

Suppose, I expected, before a **paired-samples t-test study** `(n = 40)`, that the **effect size** is going to be **negative** in direction and thus use a `half-Caushy` prior ranging from `(-Inf, 0)` over the effect size. Contrary to the expectation, the study finds `t = 5` (a pretty large, positive t-value). But why I still get so much support for the NULL hypothesis that effect size is zero?

```
require('BayesFactor')

1 / ttest.tstat(t=5, n1=40, nullInterval = c( -Inf , 0), rscale = sqrt(2)/2 , 
simple = TRUE)

# B10 
# 29.06593   *** is the Evidence in favor of the NULL that Effect Size is *ZERO*
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the reciprocal of the factor of interest, i.e. your
$$
29.06593 = \frac{P(Data|H=1)}{P(Data|H=0)}
$$

Do not use the reciprocal Bayes factor, but the original one:

```
ttest.tstat(t=5, n1=40, nullInterval = c( -Inf , 0), rscale = sqrt(2)/2 , simple = TRUE)
```

and you will get what you expect - a strong rejection of null hypothesis:

```
B10 
0.03440454
```

For a reference on reciprocal Bayes factor, you can inspect e.g. [this](http://faculty.washington.edu/kenrice/sisgbayes/2016_SISG_17_3.pdf) presentation, namely slide 52 where you can see it in the context of real world study.

Comment: Karel, I just talked to the Author of the BayesFactor package, unfortuantely your answer is wrong! Here is the BayesFactor package author's response to my inquiry: `"You applied an interval alternative of (-Inf, 0) - that is, a negative effect size - but the observed effect is positive (the t statistic is positive). So, compared to the *negative* effect sizes, the null looks really good!"`